# Create simple array by filtering array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object

```
people = [
   {fName:"George", sName:"Nina", age:20},
   {fName:"Robert", sName:"Brown", age:30},
   {fName:"Davie", sName:"Wilson", age:40}
]
```

I want to create simple array by filtering the array of object. Like this:

```
newPeople=["George Nina","Robert Brown", "Davie Wilson"]
```

Can some want help me with it?

Comment: Hi , could you please share the code , what you have tried?

Comment: Itried something like this

` const newPeople=people.filter(person=>{
    return person.fName+" "+person.lName
  })`

Comment: I have given the answer , but please mention the code that you have tried while asking the question . It tells the person has tried something and is not simply asking the question here . Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new comer , I would tell you to please check what is the format of asking a question . For now I am answering below :

```
var arr= [{fName:"George", sName:"Nina", age:20},
        {fName:"Robert", sName:"Brown", age:30},
        {fName:"Davie", sName:"Wilson", age:40}]

arr.map(obj=> { return obj.fName+" "+obj.sName});
```

Comment: Good to hear . Hope you dont mind accepting the answer. happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map(el=>{return `${el.fName} ${el.sName}`})
```

This will work. You can simply use the string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#:~:text=Description,assigned%20values%20(including%20undefined%20).) which returns a new array with the same length of the input array elements and it won't mutate the input array. It will create a new array

See the below snippet code, also since its a single line you can avoid return and curly braces too.

```js
let input = [{
    fName: "George",
    sName: "Nina",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    fName: "Robert",
    sName: "Brown",
    age: 30
  },
  {
    fName: "Davie",
    sName: "Wilson",
    age: 40
  }
]

let output = input.map(obj => `${obj.fName} ${obj.sName}`)
// you can destructure and write as shown below
/*let output = input.map(({
  fName,
  sName
}) => `${fName} ${sName}`)
*/

console.log(output)
```